# Protected property from request

Tags: php, laravel

I have an Axios post request which sends a phone number to my Laravel backend. It was working fine until I deleted a column in my database. It still returns a 201 but the value isn't updated. When I `dd()` the request, it's now a protected property instead of how it was before:

```
#json: Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ParameterBag {#35
    #parameters: array:1 [
      "field" => array:2 [
        "phone_number" => "079600565197"
        "id" => 35
      ]
    ]
  }
```

So whereas before I could do:

```
$account->phone_number = $request->get('phone_number');
$account->save();
```

All it saves is `null`.

When I check the request in devtools it looks fine:

```
field: {phone_number: "07960065197", id: 35}
```

But I can't access the data inside `field`.

Is there a way I can either convert this back to how it was before, or access the nested data directly? Any tips would be a great help.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it is because you are tryng to get `'phone_number'` attribute from your url query attributes. Try doing this: `$request->input('phone_number')` instead of  `$request->get('phone_number')`.

Comment: It still returns null for some reason

Comment: Sorry got confused it should return the `get()` should still return the correct input. Looks like your `'phone_number'` attribute is nested inside `'field'`. Try: `$request->input('field.phone_number')`

Comment: What $request->get('phone_number'); will return if you dd it?

Comment: If I change it to ```$request->field['phone_number']``` it works, no idea why it changed though.

Comment: @Daniel_Knights it's because you are sending your data nested inside a field attribute in your frontend. So the 'phone_number' attribute doesn't exist in the root of your request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are nesting your `'phone_number'` attribute inside the `'field'` attribute.

To retrieve nested attributes from your request do this:

```
$request->input('field.phone_number')
```

Comment: Thanks Robert, this works. As does this: ```$request->field['phone_number']```. Still don't know why it changed though.

Comment: No problem, It probably changed because some code was changed in your frontend's ajax request.